How to retrieve Secrets (e.g., API keys) in Snowflake Notebooks
I am currently trying out Snowflake Notebooks (in preview). I could not find any information on how to handle secrets, such as API keys.
I know I can create secrets in Snowflake, but I can't figure out how to access them from a Notebook. There is nothing on this in the Notebook documentation.
In the Secret API reference there is a description on how "to retrieve credentials contained in a secret you created", but I cannot make this work in a Snowflake Notebook.
Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Have you tried creating a user defined function as show in the Secret API reference to retrieve the secret, and then calling the UDF from the notebook?

I had the same issue for retrieving username and password secrets object, my workaround was to create a function to retrieve the secret and then call it in my notebook. Adapt this code to use API keys.
First create an integration:
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION my_external_endpoints
ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = ('database.schema.your_secret_string_name')
ENABLED = true;

Then create this function that will retrieve the info for you:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_secret_username_password()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'get_secret_username_password'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (my_external_endpoints)
SECRETS = ('cred' = your_secret_string_name)
AS
$$
import _snowflake
import json

def get_secret_username_password():
  username_password_object = _snowflake.get_username_password('cred')

  username_password_dictionary = {
      "Username": username_password_object.username,
      "Password": username_password_object.password
  }

  return json.dumps(username_password_dictionary)
$$;

In your notebook retrieve the info:
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
import json

session = get_active_session()

result = session.sql(f"""
    SELECT get_secret_username_password()
""").collect()

creds = json.loads(result[0][0])

username = creds["Username"]
password = creds["Password"]


Thanks a lot, this worked! However, this seems unnecessarily complicated, as I will need to write a secret-retrieve-function for each secret. Let's hope Snowflake comes up with a better solution in the future!

I hear you, I was looking for a way to pass in the secrets string name and get back the value but Snowflake for some reason didn't allow that. I'm interested if someone has a solution to this.

In Snowflake Notebooks, you can create a new stored procedure that integrates with an API and use it in subsequent cells.
import json
import requests
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import sproc
import _snowflake

def get_secret():
    return _snowflake.get_oauth_access_token('cred')

# Function to call a your API
def your_api_get(path, params=None):
    url = f"https://api.example.com/{path}"  
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {get_secret()}"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    raise Exception(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")

# Stored procedure to integrate with a API
@sproc(
    packages=["snowflake-snowpark-python", "requests"],
    secrets={"cred": "your_api_secret_name"},
    replace=True,
    external_access_integrations=["your_external_access_integration"],
)
def api_call(session: snowpark.Session, path: str, params: dict) -> dict:
    return your_api_get(path, params)

You can call this stored procedure in subsequent cells like this
res_data = json.loads(api_call('/data/query', params))

Replace the placeholders with your own API details.

While @Amito gave the correct answer, here's a slightly shorter version if you just need to return a string, such as an API key:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_my_api_key()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'retrieve_my_api_key'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (my_integration)
SECRETS = ('cred' = my_api_key)
AS
$$
import _snowflake

def retrieve_my_api_key():   
  my_api_key = _snowflake.get_generic_secret_string('cred') 
  return my_api_key
$$;

and in the notebook:
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
session = get_active_session()
results = session.sql('SELECT retrieve_my_api_key()').collect()
secret_my_api_key = results[0][0]


This article was the closest to helping solve this issue for me, but the external access integration from Amito did not work because it was missing allowed_network_rules. I also didn't know what type of network rule to use. This code finally worked for me, though you'll need to update the network rule value_list to meet your needs.
CREATE SECRET IF NOT EXISTS test_secret
TYPE = GENERIC_STRING
SECRET_STRING = 'test_secret_value'
COMMENT = 'test secret for python func development';

CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE allow_all_rule
MODE = 'EGRESS'
TYPE = 'HOST_PORT'
VALUE_LIST = ('0.0.0.0:443','0.0.0.0:80')
COMMENT = 'Network rule for external access integration';

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION test_ext_acc_integration
ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = ('ALLOW_ALL_RULE')
ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = ('TEST_SECRET')
ENABLED = true;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_python_secret_test()
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE PYTHON
    RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.11
    HANDLER = 'get_secret'
    PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
    EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (test_ext_acc_integration)
    SECRETS = ('cred' =  test_secret)
AS
$$
import _snowflake

def get_secret():
  secret_value = _snowflake.get_generic_secret_string('cred')
  return secret_value
$$;

